# How to get Total Fee data of last 6 months by using date field - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model as below,

```
class Visits(models.Model):
visit_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
fees = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False,  max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to get data for last six months (including current month) total fees month wise

Example:

```
{
July : 750, 
June : 800,
May : 500,
April : 200,
March: 450,
Febraury: 310 }
```

How to get done this by having date field.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to get the month from `visit_date`, sort it, group by month and calculate the sums grouped by month.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

offset_date = '2022-02-01'  # All Visits after this date (included) will be used

fees_by_month = (Visits
                 .objects
                 .filter(visit_date__gte=offset_date)
                 .annotate(month=Extract('visit_date', 'month'))
                 .order_by('month')  # Important to get correct output
                 .values('month')    # Group by month
                 .annotate(sum=Sum('fees')))
```

resulting in

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 2, 'sum': 310}, {'month': 3, 'sum': 450}, {'month': 4, 'sum': 200}, {'month': 5, 'sum': 500}, {'month': 6, 'sum': 800}, {'month': 7, 'sum': 750}]>
```

Comment: Hi, its working great!.. But sometime, if a month not having any fee entry its not being in the list. how to solve it.. example, if feb to august list, jun not having any fee entry it should show june 0 instead of not coming in the list. how to do it? is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: @SaravananRagavan No, this is not trivial for Django ORM. If you had all dates/months in a model there might be a way, but otherwise no. Well at least not in ORM. You could postprocess your result and add missing months with python in the view.